# Is it posible in Android to allows the phone to have two unlock pin codes?

Tags: android

What I would like to do is create an app on the Android that allows the following:

Allows the phone to have two unlock pin codes. One unlock code will the the master "normal" code. The second unlock code will allow the user to receive and send texts, make and receive phone calls, store pictures, and contacts that will not show up in the "normal" screen.

Comment: Can an application do said task (or validate any PIN codes) anyway? If not then ..

Comment: Android 4.2 supports multiple users :)

Comment: @pts I trying to know the same thing that Can I access my application before the system lock screen?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with an app. Apps cannot change system behaviour unless they are 'system administrator' apps. Even those cannot do such fine grained control, only impose restrictions on unlock code strength, camera use and device encryption. As others have noted, Android 4.2 supports multiple users (on tablets only), which gives you a separate unlock code for each user. Additionally, some operations that affect the whole device, such as adding new users, adding or removing trusted certificates, accessing the secure element, etc. are reserved for the first/primary user. You can't place calls with a tablet though, so multiple users doesn't really apply to calling/SMS.